# Why does scipy.signal.correlate2d() use such an inefficient algorithm?

Tags: python, scipy

A few days ago, I started a script to utilize scipy.signal.correlate2d to compute the 2-D autocorrelation of a 4096x4096 image.  The exact call is

```
zauto = signal.correlate2d(image, image, mode='full', boundary='wrap')
```

Three days later, it's still running with no end in sight.  I eventually realized it must be doing a brute-force element-by-element convolution, a procedure that goes with N^2, thus 4096^4 = *281 trillion* multiplies and adds.

In the meantime, I eventually figured out that I can get the desired result by taking the 2-D FFT of the image, converting it to a 2-D power spectrum, and then taking the inverse FFT;  i.e.,

```
image -= np.mean(image)            # remove constant bias
zfft = np.fft.fft2(image)          # take 2-D FFT (complex)
zpower = zfft*np.conjug(zfft)      # convert to power spectrum
zauto = np.real(np.ifft2(zpower))  # take inverse FFT
zauto /= zauto[0,0]                # normalize
```

The above lines take under one minute to complete.

My question:  why doesn't scipy.signal.correlate2d include at least the option to use the much more efficient algorithm when feasible rather than letting the user discover the hard way that it simply can't be used on larger images?

Comment: Make an enhancement request in a new issue: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Congratulations, you've rediscovered the [convolution theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution_theorem)!

Joking aside, `scipy` *does* give you the option of doing convolution in either the signal or Fourier domain, just not with the explicit 2D method you've selected. The [`signal.correlate`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.correlate.html#scipy.signal.correlate) function will handle N-dimensional convolution, and will either try to select a good method for you (the `method="auto"` argument), or you can force it to use the one you want.

But note that the Fourier-method is not always the most efficient. While the FFT-based convolution does have better asymptotic complexity than the direct method, the constant factors are larger. There is a significant amount of book-keeping and setup required to perform the FFTs involved, while the direct method is dead-simple. This is the reason for the `"auto"` option and the [`choose_conv_method`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.choose_conv_method.html#scipy.signal.choose_conv_method) function: the "best" method depends on the sizes of the inputs.

As to *why*? I can't really answer that, other than to say that the library authors might have felt that most people using these tools would be aware of the trade-offs. The `scipy.signal` module provides a number of similar methods, and several parts of the documentation make clear the fact that FFT-based convolution is not a panacea.

Comment: I'll admit that I found the correlate2d function in a search and didn't further explore the scipy.signal library.  Still, perhaps the doc page for correlated2d should alert users to the issue, as it does not currently even state what method is used.

Comment: @GrantPetty Agreed, it's sort of odd that the `correlate2d` method is the only one that doesn't mention the tradeoffs. Maybe file an issue on GH, it could help others too!